# Which technologies for kiosk web app

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, installation, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I've to run web project in a kiosk mode, this include the possibility to :

- hide the native cursor
- force the fullscreen / Prevent exit fullscreen
- remove the possibility to leave the app in any way
- should be kind of easy to launch in case of crash or rebooting

This application will be:

- for only one OS (probably windows)
- always launch on the same screen
- People will only have access to a touch screen (no keyboard, mouse, or any accessible port)

For the moment I've read about Electron which is possible to launch in kiosk mode, but I'm afraid of performances issues and it's not a necessity for me to get to get a .exe/.dmg ..

I also look at Chrome app which seems really fit my need with the kiosk mode but google has deprecated it since 2016 (https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)

Is there is a cleaner solution for this type of need? Some solution that I would have missed.

Answer (score 0):

chrome in kiosk mode should work fine. we are working on a similar app, no keyboard,mouse and it appears good. i haven't gotten to hiding the mouse yet.

launch chrome with (not sure what --kiosk-printing means but it makes it work).

```
                " --kiosk --kiosk-printing "
```

Comment: If I remember well, I think that we try this out. But there were some windows shurtcut that was still accessible, like swapping from screen edges to open like the 
 "notification center".
For the mouse we directly used the "cursor: none" property in our css.